# Common Logic in Microservices

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

we have developed 5 to 6 microservices, independent of each other having its own database as per the microservices principles.

Now we are refactoring the services and have the following dilemma.

1. All microservices send and receive messages from ActiveMQ.

   - the configuration details of ActiveMQ ( JmsListenerContainerFactory , Handlers etc) Boiler plate code is repeating in all these services.
2. All microservices are having audit functionality ex: Audit of Order creation, update and delete.
       - AOP Logic related configuration also repeating in all these microservices.

Is it a good practice to move these common logic to a library or a common service.
Please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: yes you can make to having duplicate code issue

Comment: but use library or dependency  not as micro service

Comment: Build a custom spring starter

Answer (score 6):

I was in the same boat when started using micro-services at work.

We've identified the following "common" places. This list is not full of course, but just to give an idea:

- Messaging infrastructure (producer / consumer, pub-sub) like in your case
- Metering infrastructure  (some extensions we've used for micrometer)
- Logging configurations (the same appenders, patterns, slightly different behavior for windows/linux/mac os machines, etc)
- Spring actuator extensions (additional endpoints)
- Error handling
- Relational database configuration extensions (actuator health-checks, some driver-s extensions, and so forth)

The solution that we've come with is to provide a different type of artifact from the maven's Point Of View. This would have packaging jar and won't be dependent on spring boot at all (besides the required parts like actuator's API if required).

We've created a maven module per item from the aforementioned list that by itself had a `@Configuration` what was able to load all the required beans. If you want it to get resolved with "autoconfiguration" consider using "spring factories". We've used this method and it worked great for us. Alternatively if you want to be more explicit, you can create an annotation, like `@EnableXYZ` that will essentially import the configuration of the jar module:

```
 @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Import({CommonErrorHandlingConfiguration.class})
 public @interface EnableErrorHandling {

 }

 ...

 @Configuration 
 public class CommonErrorHandlingConfiguration {
   // beans relevant for error handling appear here
 }
```

In this example, there is a module called `common-error-handling` and it contains both of the aforementioned classes.

Now your micro-services have it as a dependency and can use this `@EnableErrorHandling` annotation to activate the `CommonErrorHandlingConfiguration`

We've also figured out that there are two kinds of common libraries like this. Something that is relevant for all microservices (like logging, metering, etc) and something that can be relevant for one microservice and completely irrelevant for another.

So as a solution we've made all our microservice type jars (with spring boot plugin, integration testing and so forth) extending from one "common-microservice" pom.xml that actually has defined all these common dependencies.

So there was no need to re-define dependencies for each microservice if they're relevant for all services.

It also worth mentioning that this approach can only work as long as all the micro-services share the same technology, otherwise using side-car containers can be more appropriate in same case.

Answer (score 1):

As @harkesh kumar suggested, you could provide dependencies that all micro-services could use in general.The dependency should have an architecture that enables flexibility so that the different micro-services that adopt the dependency could make changes as per their needs.

For instance, you could provide ActiveMQ configurations as a separate dependency to be added while providing customization through `application.yml` keys or overriding the configurations manually.That way all the micro-services that do not require the default configuration will have an option to do so.

[Read](https://medium.com/microservices-in-practice/microservices-in-practice-7a3e85b6624c)

Comment: I agree with @Ananthapadmanabhan.
but notice that any changes you do in the common library, will at to be updated in all the microservices

Comment: @asfmlr I think the issue you are referring to can be handled from the deployment perspective. If I can have the common library in a central repository(Nexus) and when ever a change needs to be done in the library it gets pushed to Nexus and the next time the service undergoes the build, the service gets the new version.

Comment: I agree @iamL, but this things creating inconsistent between what you have in the repo to what is actually in prod and in example for us it's hard to know what is actually running on prod